# Prove that $f(x)=ax+b$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Im stuck in this exercise:

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x) \space\space\ \forall x\land \forall h $

Prove that $\space f(x)=ax+b$

I think it's something easy but I can not find a concrete proof.

I would appreciate a hint. Thanks

Comment: $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$ is not possible for $h=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying the condition with $x=0$ we have $f(h) = f(0) + h f'(0)$ for all $h$, *et voilà*.

Comment: Thanks! it's easier than i expected.

Comment: What if $h = 0$?  Then you have $\frac {f(x)-f(x)}0 = \frac 00 = f'(x)$ and that's not defined.

Comment: @fleablood When $h \ne 0$, the assumption implies $f(h) = f(0) + h f'(0)$. When $h = 0$, we automatically have $f(h) = f(0) + h f'(0)$.

Comment: @fleablood : I think the issue is with the question. It needs to say that the condition holds for all $x$ and all non-zero $h$. And then the relation $f(h) =f(0)+hf'(0)$ holds for all $h$ as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am elaborating @angryavian 's answer.

When $x=0$, observe that

$$ \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}= f'(0) \iff f(h)=f'(0)h+f(0) \hspace{4mm} \forall h$$

Thus, by switching the letter from $h$ to $x$,

$$f(x)=f'(0)x+f(0)  $$

where $a=f'(0)$ and $b=f(0)$ in this case.

Comment: You haven't said what $y$ is.

Comment: I think it refers to y=h

Comment: @Shaun Thanks, I edited

Comment: You're welcome. That's better :)

Comment: "$\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}= f'(0) \iff f(h)=f'(0)h+f(0) \hspace{4mm} \forall h$.  That's not true.  It isn't true for $h = 0$.

Comment: @fleablood nits. you're picking them.

Comment: As far as nits go that is a pretty humongous one.  It's fairly important that you can't divide by $0$.

Comment: @fleablood I made it better to read.  We are just changing the letter.